# Como atribuir o valor de uma variavel em javascript, dentro de php?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
      var carrinho = $("#carrinho").val();
      //alert("Carrinho " + carrinho);
      var i;
      var soma = 0;
      for (i = 1; i <= carrinho; i++) {
        //alert(i);
        var x = $("#p" + i).val();
        //alert(i+"---- "+x);

        var y = $("#txt_p" + i).val();
        //alert(i+ "------ "+y);

        var z = $("#preco" + i).val();
        //alert(i + "------ "+z);
        var total = x * z;
        //alert("Total = "+ total);
        var atualiza = total;
        //alert("Valor atualizado = "+ total);
        soma = soma + total;
        $("#txt_p" + i).text(atualiza + "€");
        $("#total").text(soma + "€");
        $("#teste" + i).val(x);


        //a variavel x irá armazenar a quatidade atual do produto

          <?php
              $c = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
              for ($k1 = 0; $k1 < $c; $k1++) {
                  $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$k1]["item_quantity"] = x;
              }
          ?>
         }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Tem como fazer isso não. Se fosse o contrário PHP -> JavaScript daria, mas de JS -> PHP não tem como.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é enviar esta informação via ajax.

Comment: @WictorChaves e como faço isso? por acaso nuncva trabalhei com ajax... :s

Comment: @WictorChaves percebi amigo! Já implementei o seu código no meu projeto mas ainda assim n atualiza a variavel de sessão pois imaginando que eu mudo de pagina e volto de novo os valores da quantidade são os mesmos quando o utilizador introduziu o produto no seu carrinho e n os novos valores da qta que ele introduziu antes de sair. esse é, ainda o meu problema...

Comment: Tente depurar apertando f12

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "action.php",
  data: { x: x }
});
```

Aqui estou definindo o método de envio, a `url` do arquivo `php` no qual será enviado via `post` a variável `x`.

[Documentação do ajax utilizando jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Como utilizei o método `post` fiz o arquivo `action.php` da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$c = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
for ($k1 = 0; $k1 < $c; $k1++) {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$k1]["item_quantity"] = $_POST['x'];
}
```

Repare que estou pegando via `post` a variável `x`, que foi definida em `data` no nosso `ajax`.

Como ficaria o código completo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        var carrinho = $("#carrinho").val();
        //alert("Carrinho " + carrinho);
        var i;
        var soma = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= carrinho; i++) {
        //alert(i);
        var x = $("#p" + i).val();
        //alert(i+"---- "+x);

        var y = $("#txt_p" + i).val();
        //alert(i+ "------ "+y);

        var z = $("#preco" + i).val();
        //alert(i + "------ "+z);
        var total = x * z;
        //alert("Total = "+ total);
        var atualiza = total;
        //alert("Valor atualizado = "+ total);
        soma = soma + total;
        $("#txt_p" + i).text(atualiza + "€");
        $("#total").text(soma + "€");
        $("#teste" + i).val(x);

        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "some.php",
          data: { x: x }
        });

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

> Obs: por padrão ao utilizar a função `ajax` do `jquery` a opção
>   `async` esta como `true`, ou seja, ele vai chamar o código `php` e vai
>   continuar o processamento do script antes mesmo do termino do
>   processamento do `php` finalizar, caso deseje que isso não aconteça,
>   caso deseje que ele espere a finalização do código `php` para
>   continuar o processo normal do `script`, você deve usar o `async` como
>   `false`, desta forma:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   method: "POST",
>   url: "some.php",
>   async: false,
>   data: { x: x }
> });
> ```